# Why does target="blank" work?

Tags: html

The following target attribute value will open a link in a new tab:

```
 <a href="http://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank">Visit W3Schools</a>
```

Why does the following (with underscore in `blank` omitted) do the same apparently in all browsers?  It's a different value?

```
 <a href="http://www.w3schools.com" target="blank">Visit W3Schools</a>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<a target="_blank|_self|_parent|_top|framename">
```

`target="blank"` tries to open an existing frame named 'blank' , so you could use any other word instead of `blank` , for example `target="whatever"` see here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/xxeewuw5/)

so, because the frame(window) with name 'blank' doesn't exist, it opens a new window and you have the impression that is the same thing with `_blank`, but `_blank` is a reserved value for the target attribute

`target="_blank"` opens the given url in a new window
`target="whatever"` targets a window named 'whatever' , if that window does not exist, it creates a new window

for more info read here **[HTML  target Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp)**

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 1):

target=blank opens the link in a new window entitled blank where target=_blank just opens it in a new window. So if u have two links w/ target=blank then they will both open up in the same new window but if u have the two links w/ target=_blank they will both open up in their own new window.

blank targets an existing frame or window called "blank". A new window is created only if "blank" doesn't already exist.
_blank is a reserved name which targets a new, unnamed window.